Next.js redirect user from api handlers
I was implementing Discord authentication on my site with Next.js, but I'm encountering an issue with the redirect from the API handler:
Discord sends the data to /api/auth/callback/discord, and I need to perform a redirect from this API handler to /dashboard.
How can I do this from the backend?
Here’s the code:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getDiscordUser } from "@/lib/discord";
import { createUser } from "@/lib/user";
import mongoClient from "@/lib/mongodb";
import crypto from "crypto";
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { hash } from "@/lib/crypto";

const mongo = (await mongoClient).db(process.env.DATABASE_NAME);

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
    const cookieStore = cookies()

    const code = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("code");

    if(!code) return NextResponse.redirect(`${process.env.DISCORD_AUTH_URL}`)

    const tokenResponse = await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: new URLSearchParams({
            client_id: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID ?? "",
            client_secret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET ?? "",
            code: code,
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            redirect_uri: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/auth/callback/discord`,
            scope: "email identify"
        }).toString(),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        }
    }).then(res => res.json())

    const user = await getDiscordUser(tokenResponse.access_token)

    const token = await crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("base64url")

    createUser(user.id, hash(token), user.email)

    cookieStore.set("token", token, { maxAge: 604800 })
    cookieStore.set("global_name", user.global_name, { maxAge: 604800 })
    cookieStore.set("username", user.username, { maxAge: 604800 })
    cookieStore.set("avatar", user.avatar, { maxAge: 604800 })
    cookieStore.set("id", user.id, { maxAge: 604800 })

    return NextResponse.redirect(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/dashboard/projects`)
}

Obviously, now is returning a 307 status code to Discord as a response.
I'm using the app router.
Thank you in advance.
